# I want to spawn my zombies in my game at a random location but I want to make sure to not spawn the inside the buildings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Currently in my script I am spawning in 125 zombies randomly all over my map however with my current code it just spawns them everywhere including inside the buildings. I want to keep the random spawns so i can't make exact spawn locations. Does anyone know how to block them from spawning inside buildings?

My current code for spawning them in (I am a noob so sorry if code is bad/messy)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ZombieRandomSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ZK;
    public int xPos;
    public int zPos;
    public int enemyCount;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        while (enemyCount < 125)
        {
            xPos = Random.Range(1, 165);
            zPos = Random.Range(1, 215);
            Instantiate(ZK, new Vector3(xPos, 0.3f, zPos), Quaternion.identity);
            enemyCount = enemyCount + 1;
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Are buildings e.g. prefabs or game objects in your scene? If so, you could probably enumerate them, save their bounding boxes and when spawning enemies, generate new coordinates if the ones you've generated are inside those bounding boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I would make an array of empty game objects that would be the possible spawn locations.  Then place them anywhere you want, outside of the buildings.  Then each time a zombie spawns, make it randomly select a spawn location from the array of locations that you made.

Answer (score 1):

I would **not** use a `SphereCast` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67065359/7111561)!

As the name says it casts a sphere along a certain direction and checks if it hits anything on its way.

You probably rather would use an [`Physics.CheckSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckSphere.html) which checks for any colliders around a certain **point** within a certain radius without returning them since we are not interested in the hit `Collider`s anyway but only in the return value (`bool`).

In this specific use-case though it might not work as expected since in `Start` it might happen that not all physics related things are correctly initialized yet. I would wait until the first [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) call like e.g.

```
// Adjust this via the Inspector
[Tooltip("How far away from any collider do zombies have to spawn?")]
[SerializeField] private float zombySpawnDistanceThreashold = 0.3f;

// Yes, if you make Start return IEnumerator 
// Unity automatically runs it as a Coroutine
private IEnumerator Start ()
{
    // Wait for the first physics Update
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate ();

    // We don't actually care about the hits
    // We only need to know IF we hit anything at all
    // But this is way more efficient then everytime allocating a new array
    var hits = new Collider[1];
    while (enemyCount < 125)
    {
        // I assume you don't need to have exact INT values but can use any FLOAT value between them
        // If that's the case make sure to use the FLOAT version here
        var xPos = Random.Range(1f, 165f);
        var zPos = Random.Range(1f, 215f);
        var spawnPos = new Vector3(xPos, 0.3f, zPos);

        // If we hit something we have to continue and pick a new random position
        // Note: You might want/need to ignore the floor layer if your radius is too big since it would count as hit
        if(Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc(spawnPos, zombySpawnDistanceThreashold, hits) > 0) continue;

        Instantiate(ZK, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        // (Not sure if needed) Resimulate the physics to take the newly added zomby collider into account
        Physics.Simulate(0.00001f);
        enemyCount++;
    }
}
```

---

As an alternative to skipping the spawn in case if a hit you could also use [`Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc.html) and then use [`Physics.ComputePenetration`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.ComputePenetration.html) in order to  get a direction and distance of where and how far you have to move the zomby in order to push it out of the hit collider.

Comment: Good call didn't know about Physics.CheckSphere. Cool and powerful function.

Answer (score 0):

For an easy approach, I would consider looking into [spherecast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html). Before spawning a zombie, cast a sphere and if it hits a building then try another spot to spawn. There is the potential for this to take a lot of computational time as it is randomly picking points and checking if it is valid. There is the case where it continually randomly picks points inside of buildings.

A more solid approach would be to predefined the bounds of where your buildings are, then only random pick places outside of these ranges. It also heavily depends on how large your building is or how many buildings you have. It is a rather vague question so more detail can help give a more exact answer.